# Coffeescript compiler and watcher

Tags: javascript, build, coffeescript, watch

I am very new with coffeescript, I am working on a dev environment and I would like to ask from experiment user what they use for:

- Automatic Coffescript Compiler
- Automatic Coffescript watcher

I came accross `Cake`, `Grunt`.

I just one the best practice before for compiling and watching my coffescript code.

Comment: "best practice" for what? Do you have any specific problem with those tools?

Comment: I am editing better.

Comment: I am concerned about the performance. And I simply asked why some users are working with one instead of another.

Comment: don't forget to validate the answer if you found it meaningful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cake is the option you are looking for, it is light and it does the job.

here is the main script for compilation and watching.

```
fs     = require 'fs'
{exec} = require 'child_process'

appFiles  = [
  # omit src/ and .coffee to make the below lines a little shorter
  'content/scripts/statusbar'
  'content/scripts/command/quickMacro'
  'content/scripts/command/selectionTools/general'
]

task 'build', 'Build single application file from source files', ->
  appContents = new Array remaining = appFiles.length
  for file, index in appFiles then do (file, index) ->
    fs.readFile "src/#{file}.coffee", 'utf8', (err, fileContents) ->
      throw err if err
      appContents[index] = fileContents
      process() if --remaining is 0
  process = ->
    fs.writeFile 'lib/app.coffee', appContents.join('\n\n'), 'utf8', (err) ->
      throw err if err
      exec 'coffee --compile lib/app.coffee', (err, stdout, stderr) ->
        throw err if err
        console.log stdout + stderr
        fs.unlink 'lib/app.coffee', (err) ->
          throw err if err
          console.log 'Done.'
```

More info in [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/%5BHowTo%5D-Compiling-and-Setting-Up-Build-Tools)